# Given an arbitrary expression or string, identify variables required to run expression

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a simple expression, like:

```
ifelse(x < 0, 1,0)
```

I would like to pass this to some function, such as `all.vars` as provided by @RichScriven. So the result would be the character vector: `x`

```
rowSums(dat[c("x","y","z")])
```

In this case I would like to see:  `c("dat", "x","y","z")`.

However, there are more complex examples:

```
ifelse(x < 0, rowsums(dat[c("x","y","z"]), 0)
```

In this case I would like to see: `c("x", "dat", "x","y","z")`

It looks like the first part of my question was answered by `all.vars`, but that doesn't work for the second part.

Comment: `all.vars(quote(ifelse(x < 0, 1, 0)))` works for the first one.  But on the second that won't fly because of the character values in the column subset.

Comment: @akaDrHouse I honestly can't think of a good solution! Also downvotes with no constructive commentary not chill.

Comment: @RichScriven `all.vars` is a good start thanks!

Comment: Well, I gave you a downvote because your question doesn't sufficiently define your goal. What does "identify requirements" mean? Do you want to get all input variables in an expression? But then, why would you want those characters in the second example? This is just an unclear question. I should vote to close actually.

Comment: Thanks @roland I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Why do you want that? It would be cheaper to handle errors instead of checking whether input is subsetted and gives a valid result.

Comment: Sorry @BrandonBertelsen. I thought you were kidding.  I did not downvote though!

Comment: @Roland Imagine you have 50,000 modelling variables that are constantly being generated and added to by a team of modellers and you want to automatically identify if you have the variables needed to generate the definitions they provide.

Comment: @akaDrHouse no problem! I know it seems so simple, but I can't figure out a good approach.

Comment: Do you mean something like exists()?

Comment: In an expression like `rowSums(dat[c(1, 2, 3)])` would you need `c("dat", "1", "2", "3")` returned? Or, in one like `paste("x", "y")` would you need `c("x", "y")`? In the first case, `dat` is _required_ to have >= 3 columns, while in the second case, "x" and "y" are just character arguments and the expression has no requirements to be valid.

Comment: Well, I think you need to consider a different approach. The only idea I have is not practical. You could follow the parse tree with a recursive function and have it return the first parameter of `[` or the second parameter if that exists. But there are just too many inputs that would break this. As I said, use `tryCatch` to handle wrong input.

Comment: @alexis_laz I've added a more complicated example to show what I'm looking for. Now that I look at it a little more. I think I can get exactly what I want by regex extraction of quoted characters + `all.vars`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen. My original comment was because I did not fully understand what you were asking for. Given the re-statement of the question, I understand this isn't trivial!

Comment: Thanks all for feedback here. Was having a bit of trouble getting at exactly what I neeed. Appreciate the downvotes + commentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following should do what you want:

```
recurse_ast <- function(x) {
  if (is.atomic(x) || is.name(x)){}
  else if (is.call(x)) {
    if(identical(quote(`[`),x[[1]])) {
      ret <- c()
      for(i in seq(2,length(x))) {
        if(is.call(x[[i]]) && x[[i]][[1]] == 'c') {
          for(j in seq(2,length(x[[i]]))) {
            if(!is.name(x[[i]][[j]])){
              ret <- c(ret,x[[i]][[j]]) 
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ret
    } else unlist(lapply(x,recurse_ast))
  } else if (is.pairlist(x) || is.expression(x)) {
      unlist(lapply(x,recurse_ast))
  } else {
    # User supplied incorrect input
    stop("Don't know how to handle type ", typeof(x), 
         call. = FALSE)
  }
}

get_requirements <- function(x) {
  c(all.vars(x),recurse_ast(x))
}
```

For all of your examples this has the correct result (having corrected a small syntax error in your last example):

```
> get_requirements(quote(ifelse(x < 0, 1,0)))
[1] "x"
> get_requirements(quote(rowSums(dat[c("x","y","z")])))
[1] "dat" "x"   "y"   "z"  
> get_requirements(quote(ifelse(x < 0, rowsums(dat[c("x","y","z")], 0))))
[1] "x"   "dat" "x"   "y"   "z"
```

Edit: Looking at the last output it is however probably advisable to keep the results of `recurse_ast` and `all.vars` separate since there is no way to distinguish between the variable `x` and the string "x" used in subsetting. Probably keeping the variable that is being subset would be useful too.

**Edit:** If the expression is only available as a string the following is possible:

```
> get_requirements_from_string <- function(s) {
+   get_requirements(parse(text=s))
+ }
> get_requirements_from_string("ifelse(x < 0, 1, 0)")
 [1] "x"
```

Comment: This is awesome. I just tested it against a bunch of edge cases and it works well even against single quoted requirements.

Comment: Is there an adjustment we could make here for situations where the input is a string, I mean, already quoted, `req <- "ifelse(x < 0, 1, 0)"` `get_requirements(req)`

Comment: Yes - see my edit. I had to add a case for `is.expression(x)` which was missing since it was not necessary before.

Comment: Ah yes, I was playing around with parse but couldn't find the magical combination. This is excellent. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Didn't work for me on first try either ;)